# How do I responsively handle a div wrapping an image and text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a div wrapping an image on the left and a div containing text on the right with some margin between the two. When the window size narrows I want the text to shrink between its max-width and min-width, the image to shrink at the same time so they stay next to each other, and only after the text shrinks to have it jump below the image.

But what happens is - as soon as the text hits the image it jumps below instead of shrinking to its min-width and trying to stay next to the image.

My code is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="headshot" src="..." />
  <div class="bio-text">
    <h3>BIO</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.headshot {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px;
}

.bio-text {
  max-width: 450px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have is that you are mixing a flexbox with min and max widths, which conflict with the layout of `.container`. One option is to assign `.bio-text` a `flex` of 250px, and let it grow to take the rest of the space. If the container cannot fit both, it will wrap the text below the image.

I have a codepen with that idea: https://codepen.io/sirech/pen/BYJJdz

Would this fit your needs?

Comment: Yes that's it! giving the text a flex of 250px was just what I needed. Thanks!!